# Delete button for each row in a table PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

```
<td style="text-align: left;">
    <?php
          echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete delete-account"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</a></button> 
                <input type="hidden" value="'. $r['user_id'] .'" name="delete[]">';
    ?>
</td>
```

I have this piece of code with this javascript:

```
$('button.delete-account').click(function(e) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: " <?php echo $r['user_id'] ?> You will not be able to undo this acction !",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        html: false
    }, function() {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    });
});
```

$r['user_id']---> this basically a function that helps me pull all the user from my database, for this example, it will pull all the user_id.

Problem is I have got different users in each row, and when I click on the delete button I am getting the same user_id not individual id's.

How would I be able to call each user individually???

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Why do you have more than one user in each row?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean one user in each row, instead each user in separate row

Comment: I have updated my question, sorry

Comment: Can you show us your table? Screenshot or html

Comment: Yeah sure, https://gyazo.com/2faba8848e6d09f3f14f268a6847de46

Comment: why not set the value on the delete button .. that way you know which user you want to delete by getting the value of the button in your jquery

Comment: I haven't covered all the rest of the columns apart from the delete one

Comment: @DTH , would you be able to show me an example, I didn't quiet understand what you meant. Thanks

Comment: I strongly agree with @DTH: It looks like you are writing JavaScript with PHP, hence the above handler needs to be written for every row (!) which only comes with disadvantages (performance, maintainability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id from input as well (I presume you are using jquery)

```
var id = $(e).parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

**Not tested**

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Not able to fully understand your code, but you get my idea by looking at this fiddle: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pb3c6fr1/2/)

Setting the id of the user using the value of the created buttons is one way to do it. This way you will assign a value to each created button, which represents the id of the user ..

```
<td style="text-align: left;">
    <?php
          echo '<button type="button" value="'. $r['user_id'] .'" class="btn btn-danger delete delete-account"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</a></button>';
    ?>
</td>
```

And then in your jquery get the value of the button clicked by using jquery's **$(this)** to get the clicked button and the get the value by calling **.val()**. This way you will only have one handler for all your created buttons. :

```
$('button.delete-account').click(function(e) {
swal({

title: "Are you sure?",
text: $(this).val()+" You will not be able to undo this acction !",
type: "warning",
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
closeOnConfirm: false,
html: false
}, function(){
swal("Deleted!",
"Your imaginary file has been deleted.",
"success");
});
});
```

**Code not tested** ... I'm not quite able to verify how your code works so i just copied your code and made the minor change with the value thing of the button .. But most important is for you to get the idea of storing a value (id) of the user on each button, and retrieving it with $(this) in your handling..

Answer (score 1):

these two scripts will do.

show.php

```
<?php
/* 

Deletes a specific entry from the  table
*/

// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
// get id value
$id = $_GET['id'];

// delete the entry
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM *fillin* WHERE id=$id")
or die(mysql_error()); 

// redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: urlocation.php");
 }
else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
header("Location: urlocation.php");
}

?>
```

delete.php

```
    <?php
    */  Displays all data from ' table


    // connect to the database
    include('dbconnectfile.php');

    // get results from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbase") 
            or die(mysql_error());  

      // display data in table
  echo "<p><b>info</b></p>";

    echo "<table border='2' border-color='#800000' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>fill-in</th> <th>fill-in</th><th>fill-in</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>' . $row['rowname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['rowname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['rowname'] . '</td>';

            echo '<td><a HREF="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img style="width: 25px; height: 25px; " alt="" src="">Delete</a></td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
    } 

    // close table>
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

on html:

```
<td style="text-align: left;">
        <?php
              echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete delete-account"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</a></button> 
                    <input type="hidden" class="userId" value="'. $r['user_id'] .'" name="delete[]">';
        ?>
    </td>
```

on js:

```
$('button.delete-account').click(function(e) {
   var id = $(this).siblings('input.userId').val();
  swal({
   title: "Are you sure?",
   text: id + " You will not be able to undo this acction !",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
   closeOnConfirm: false,
   html: false
  }, function(){ 
   $.post( "delete.php", { userID: id } );
   swal("Deleted!",
     "Your imaginary file has been deleted.",
     "success");  
  });
});
```

on delete.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userID'])){
  $id = $_POST['userID'];
  include('connect-db.php');
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE userID = " . $id);
}
?>
```